# Formatar Hora utilizando initBinder

Tags: java, spring, datetime

Eu preciso pegar a hora com a formatação "hh:mm" porém não está funcionando, segue o erro também para melhor especificar:

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

```
Tue Dec 18 13:56:56 BRST 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Validation failed for object='cartelas'. Error count: 1
org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'cartelas' on field 'final_time': rejected value [17:20]; codes [typeMismatch.cartelas.final_time,typeMismatch.final_time,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [cartelas.final_time,final_time]; arguments []; default message [final_time]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'final_time'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse date: Unparseable date: "17:20"]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

---

Minha classe:

```
package br.com.sky.iTvMC.modelo;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

@Table(name = "CARTELAS_NEW_CHANNEL_HD")
@Entity
public class Cartelas {
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seqCart", sequenceName = 
"SEQ_CARTELAS_NEW_CHANNEL_HD", allocationSize = 1)
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seqCart")
private Long id;
private static final String server_folder = "C:'\'Projetos";

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date initial_date;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date final_date;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "hh:mm")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
private Date initial_time;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "hh:mm")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
private Date final_time;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private CelulasCartela celulas;

private String who;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public static String getServerFolder() {
    return server_folder;
}

public Date getInitial_date() {
    return initial_date;
}

public Date getFinal_date() {
    return final_date;
}

public Date getInitial_time() {
    return initial_time;
}

public Date getFinal_time() {
    return final_time;
}

public CelulasCartela getCelulas() {
    return celulas;
}

public void setFinal_time(Date final_time) {
    this.final_time = final_time;
}

public void setInitial_time(Date initial_time) {
    this.initial_time = initial_time;
}

public void setInitial_date(Date initial_date) {
    this.initial_date = initial_date;
}

public void setFinal_date(Date final_date) {
    this.final_date = final_date;
}

public void setCelulas(CelulasCartela celulas) {
    this.celulas = celulas;
}

public String getWho() {
    return who;
}

public void setWho(String who) {
    this.who = who;
}

}
```

---

Controller

```
package br.com.sky.iTvMC.controller;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import br.com.sky.iTvMC.modelo.Cartelas;
import br.com.sky.iTvMC.modelo.CelulasCartela;
import br.com.sky.iTvMC.repository.CartelasRepository;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/cartelas")
public class ClientChannelController {

@Autowired
CartelasRepository cartelaRepository;

@RequestMapping("/novo")
public ModelAndView novo() {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("cadastrarCartela");
    return mv;
}

@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm"); //yyyy-MM- 
dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ example
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
   // System.out.println("init binder");
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, "initial_time", new 
CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, "final_time", new 
CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView salvar(Cartelas cartela) {
    System.out.println("Data inicial: "+ cartela.getInitial_date());
    System.out.println("Data final: "+ cartela.getFinal_date());
    System.out.println("celula: "+ cartela.getCelulas());        
    System.out.println("hora incial: "+ cartela.getInitial_time());
    System.out.println("hora final: "+ cartela.getFinal_time());        
    cartelaRepository.save(cartela);
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("cadastrarCartela");
    mv.addObject("mensagem", "Cartela cadastrada com sucesso!");
    return mv;      
}

@ModelAttribute("todasCelulas")
public List<CelulasCartela> todasCelulas(){
    return Arrays.asList(CelulasCartela.values());
}


}
```

---

A página do formulário

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-4 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputDatacartela">Data Inicio</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-orientation="bottom" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" data-date-language="pt-BR" data-date-autoclose="true" data-date-today-highlight="true" autocomplete="off" name="initial_date"
          placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-4 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputHoraFimCartela">Hora Inicio</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group clockpicker" data-autoclose="true">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="initial_time" placeholder="00:00" autocomplete="off">
          <span class="input-group-addon"> <span
              class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $('.clockpicker').clockpicker();
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Próxima linha  -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-4 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputFimCartela">Data Final</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-orientation="bottom" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" data-date-language="pt-BR" data-date-autoclose="true" data-date-today-highlight="true" autocomplete="off" name="final_date"
          placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-4 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputFimCartela">Hora Final</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group clockpicker" data-autoclose="true">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="final_time" placeholder="00:00" autocomplete="off">
          <span class="input-group-addon"> <span
              class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $('.clockpicker').clockpicker();
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com a mensagem de erro:

> ... [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property '**final_time**'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse date: Unparseable date: **"17:20"**

Isso quer dizer que a `String` com o valor `"17:20"` foi passada para o `SimpleDateFormat` que você criou, mas não foi possível fazer o *parsing*.

Considerando o `SimpleDateFormat` criado no seu método `initBinder`:

```
// SimpleDateFormat que você criou
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
dateFormat.setLenient(false);

// tenta fazer o parsing de 17:20
Date date = dateFormat.parse("17:20");
```

Este código lança uma exceção:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "17:20"

Isso acontece porque `hh` corresponde ao campo [*Hour in am/pm*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), com valores entre 1 e 12 (por exemplo, o valor `5` pode ser tanto 5 da manhã quanto 5 da tarde).

Este `SimpleDateFormat` até *aceitaria* valores maiores que 12 para as horas, mas como você usou `setLenient(false)`, isso faz com que somente valores entre 1 e 12 sejam aceitos, e qualquer outro lance exceção.

Como você está recebendo valores maiores que 12, use `HH` (maiúsculo) para que sejam aceitos valores entre 0 e 23 (`5` é 5 da manhã e `17` é 5 da tarde):

```
// usar HH para as horas (em vez de hh)
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
dateFormat.setLenient(false);
// agora sim faz o parsing sem lançar exceção
Date date = dateFormat.parse("17:20");
```

---

#### Use o campo correto

Por padrão, `SimpleDateFormat` é leniente, o que significa que aceita quaisquer valores e tenta dar um jeito de ajustá-los ([o que pode gerar alguns resultados bem estranhos se você não tomar cuidado](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue172.html)).

Usando `setLenient(false)`, este modo permissivo é desligado e a classe se torna mais restritiva, aceitando somente valores dentro do intervalo permitido para cada campo. E se você olhar na [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), verá que existem 4 campos para a hora, cada um representado por uma letra diferente e com um intervalo específico de valores:

```
Letra   Nome do campo/valores
H       Hour in day (0-23)
k       Hour in day (1-24)
K       Hour in am/pm (0-11)
h       Hour in am/pm (1-12)
```

Como você estava usando `hh` (minúsculo), só são permitidos valores entre 1 e 12. Ao tentar fazer o parsing de `"17:20"`, ocorre a exceção, já que 17 está fora do intervalo de valores válidos para o campo `h`.

Repare que no seu caso você pode usar `HH` (maiúsculo) ou `kk` (minúsculo): o primeiro aceita meia-noite como o valor zero, e o segundo, como o valor 24. Verifique nos seus casos de uso como você recebe este valor e use o campo que for mais adequado.